# How do I route my domain name to my webapp?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am using route 53 and an Ubuntu instance on ec2.

My domain is example.com and my web app can be found at example.com:8080/my-webapp-name

I want example.com to bring me right to my web app. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should redirect requests for port 80 to your app! iptables will work...

`$ iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Ubuntu wont let any app just listen on port 80, so thats why you have to redirect. You canuse crontab to run a script with this command in it everytime the machine starts up.

Answer (score 0):

How to setup Route 53 for your domain is detailed in the AWS documentation 
You'll need to create an A record and point it to your the IP address of your EC2 instance, I would recommend using an ELB or an Elastic IP on that EC2 instance for production.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html

Answer (score 0):

Just change your application listening port from 8080 to 80, and after that, you should access to your application from example.com/my-web-app-name

(don't forget to open the port 80 on your ec2 firewall)

If you want access to your app without your application directory, change the home directory on your web server/virtual host to your web app directory.